# Change tax class for company customers outside base country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set a different tax class for company users whose billing address is outside Germany in WooCommerce. Generally, it is always 19%, but in this case, I need to set it to 0%. I have implemented this with the following code snippet. However, it only works on the checkout page. On the thank you page and invoice, it always shows 19% instead of the 0% I set with the code snippet below. What I need is to set a 0% tax class for particular orders and ensure that it remains consistent throughout the purchasing process.
Any guidance on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

```
function apply_conditionally_taxes() {
    if ( !is_admin() && !empty(WC()->cart->get_cart()) ) {  
        $billing_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
        $post_data = isset( $_POST['post_data'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_POST['post_data'] ) : '';
        parse_str( $post_data, $parsed_data );
        $billing_company = isset( $parsed_data['billing_company'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $parsed_data['billing_company'] ) : '';
        
        if ( !empty( $billing_company ) && $billing_country != 'DE'   ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'Online World' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_taxes', 99, 1 );
```

I'm providing additional details to clarify the situation. No custom forms are being utilized; instead, I'm solely relying on the standard WooCommerce checkout form, specifically focusing on the billing address field. Although the code snippet mentioned earlier functions correctly on the checkout page, it consistently reverts to the default tax rate when a user proceeds to complete the purchase.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I have added the details to the question it self. There aren't any custom fields. Further class is changing in checkout page, but it is reversing while hitting the purchase button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a script to set/update the billing company when customer input/remove a billing company in checkout. This can be done via an Ajax request targeting billing company changes in checkout page.

You need to be sure that "Online World" is the right working tax rate (for zero rate), as in WooCommerce we use "Zero rate" or better "zero-rate". So be sure to set in the first function the correct working tax rate.

The code:

```php
// Change conditionally cart items tax rate
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'alter_cart_items_tax_rate', 99, 1 );
function alter_cart_items_tax_rate( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! ( WC()->customer->get_billing_country() !== 'DE' && ! empty(WC()->customer->get_billing_company()) ) )
        return;

    // Here define the replacement tax class
    $company_tax_class_slug = 'zero-rate'; // or 'online-world';

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( $company_tax_class_slug );
    }
}

// Send Ajax request: Update customer billing company on change
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'enqueue_checkout_custom_js_script');
function enqueue_checkout_custom_js_script() {
    wc_enqueue_js( "$('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name=billing_company]', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '" . admin_url('/admin-ajax.php') . "',
            data: {
                'action' : 'billing_company_update',
                'company': $(this).val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
            }
        });
    });" );
}

// PHP AJAX Receiver: Process ajax request
add_action('wp_ajax_billing_company_update', 'set_customer_billing_company');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_billing_company_update', 'set_customer_billing_company');
function set_customer_billing_company() {
    if ( isset($_POST['company']) ) {
        $company = sanitize_text_field($_POST['company']);

        WC()->customer->set_billing_company( $company );
        WC()->customer->save();
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.